# Cakephp 3 : Error while creating and saving multiple entities from file input

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem with my cakephp3 app. I try to import some subscribers from a CSV file.
I use a Behavior to import my file (https://github.com/ProLoser/CakePHP-CSV). I haven't manage to load the plugin, so I have put the Behavior file on my project under src/Model/Behavior.
I have added the behavior to my SubscribersTable.

I have created a new view (import/export) and I have added this method to my SubscribersController :

```
public function importExport()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $data = $this->request->data;
        if(!empty($data['import_file']['name']))
        {
            $file = $data['import_file'];
            if ((isset($file['tmp_name']) &&($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)))
            {
                $subscribersData = $this->Subscribers->importCsv($file['tmp_name']);
                $entities = $this->Subscribers->newEntities($subscribersData);
                $table = $this->Subscribers;
                $table->connection()->transactional(function () use ($table, $entities) {
                    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
                        $table->save($entity, ['atomic' => false]);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data I get seems to be good, as the entities created, but, when I call $table-save(), I have this error :

```
Table "App\Model\Table\SubscribersTable" is not associated with "request"
```

I have read some other questions on stackoverflow, but I don't understand why I have this error. I am new to cakephp so I don't understand everything...

If can someone help me...

Thanks !!

EDIT : It seems during the debug, the behavior is strange. Maybe this error has nothing to see with my real problem.
Here is the debug timeline :

$table->save() call:

```
        if ($options['atomic']) {
            $success = $connection->transactional(function () use ($entity, $options) {
               return $this->_processSave($entity, $options);
            });
        } else {
             ===> $success = $this->_processSave($entity, $options);
        }
...
```

$this->_processSave call :

```
    $data = $entity->extract($this->schema()->columns(), true);
```

and during the extract, no column is retrieved because

```
 public function extract(array $properties, $onlyDirty = false)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        if (!$onlyDirty || $this->dirty($property)) {
            $result[$property] = $this->get($property);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

$onlyDirty = true and $this->dirty($property)) return false.

So, when this function is called

```
$success = $this->_insert($entity, $data);
```

as the data is null, nothing is saved.

I don't really understant the concept of dirty. In the doc, it seems it is usefull when working with BelongToMany, but this element has no link with other tables, so if someone can clarify this concept ?

SubscribersTable :

```
    <?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Entity\Subscriber;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Subscribers Model
 *
 */
class SubscribersTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('subscribers');
        $this->displayField('email');
        $this->primaryKey('email');

        $options = array(
                // Refer to php.net fgetcsv for more information
                'length' => 0,
                'delimiter' => ',',
                'enclosure' => '"',
                'escape' => '\\',
                // Generates a Model.field headings row from the csv file
                'headers' => true,
                // If true, String $content is the data, not a path to the file
                'text' => false,
        );
        $this->addBehavior('Csv', $options);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('email', 'valid', ['rule' => 'email'])
            ->allowEmpty('email', 'create');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('contact');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('company');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('postal_code');

        $validator
            ->add('vip', 'valid', ['rule' => 'boolean'])
            ->allowEmpty('vip');

        $validator
            ->add('indoor', 'valid', ['rule' => 'boolean'])
            ->allowEmpty('indoor');

        $validator
            ->add('live', 'valid', ['rule' => 'boolean'])
            ->allowEmpty('live');

        $validator
            ->add('prod', 'valid', ['rule' => 'boolean'])
            ->allowEmpty('prod');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('localisation');

        $validator
            ->allowEmpty('family');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post the complete error message including the full stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion)! Also show/describe the proper context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error (ex. mark the code with line numbers that can be matched to the stacktrace). In your case also show the involved data (`$subscribersData`). And last but not least, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks!

Comment: A controller will not emit that error message. You're generating an error from code you've not shown (or code you have shown but said it's in a different class - or simply something doesn't add up). Please clarify by editing the question.

Comment: That's right, I didn't have any error message shown. So I had to debug to understand why my data wasn't saved. During the debug, I have found this error. But it seems that during the debug, the behavior is a bit strange... Some times I have errors I don't have some other times...

Comment: You need to show the code for `SubscribersTable.php`for anyone to help you, _at least_ the bits in the stack trace which should also be in the question.

Comment: The code you've added helps to clarify that the problem isn't directly in your code. Please add `$this->request->data` **and the full stack trace for the exception** to the question. I suspect something is taking your post data verbatim and thinking from the data structure that Subscribers is associated with Request.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. As I say in my edit, I don't think that the problem exposed with request is the real problem. I think it is due to the debugger (I had some weird errors only once, so I think the debugger alter something. If I don't debug, I don't have any errors). I think the problem comes from the "dirty" concept. What do you think ?

Comment: No idea, since you're asking about things which only you can see. Please clean up your question now that you know what the problem is/was. I.e. make it at least possible for readers to see and understand whatever problem you had, deleting the irrelevant info.

Answer (score 0):

This error likely comes from inside your `SubscribersTable.php`.

If you have `$this->request ...` in that file, it will throw that error because it's attempting to find `request` as an associated model, since it's not a valid method to call from a model.

Or, if it's in your controller, you likely have `$this->Subscribers->request...`

It could also be from inside another Model if you refer to it like this: `$this->Subscribers->request ...`

Comment: Request is only used in  Controllers, like that `$this->request`. Never used with `$this->something->request`

Answer (score -1):

Ok.

As I thought, the problem wasn't this error (probably due to the use of the debugger), but it was the structure of my input file.

The input file must be formatted as indicated in this document : 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records

The problem has been resolved !

Thanks again for you help !

Comment: I am aware of that, but the question asked at the beginning (understand "the text used by people to reach this page") is totally different from what was my real problem. I doubt those who the same problem come on this page. I would have remove my question if I could, or mark it as "invalid"

Comment: Ok. I haven't seen we can modify the title. I have done the modifications. Thanks for your help AD7six

Comment: I didn't suggest changing the title. I suggested *editing the question to describe your actual problem* and *editing this answer to describe your solution*. E.g. your question seems to only include irrelevant code, and your answer makes reference to "structure of my input file" - which is nowhere. You are likely to only accumulate downvotes with your question and answer in it's current state, as it's of no use to anyone.